# API credentials are incorrect

Tags: php, paypal

I've tried to adapt the example from [PayPal APIs Getting Started Guide](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-apis-getting-started-guide) to PHP:

```
<?php

define('PAYPAL_API_USER', '<snip>');
define('PAYPAL_API_PWD', '<snip>');
define('PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE', '<snip>');
define('PAYPAL_API_APPLICATION_ID', 'APP-80W284485P519543T');

$endpoing = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount';
$headers = array(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' => PAYPAL_API_USER,
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' => PAYPAL_API_PWD,
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,

    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT' => 'JSON',
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'JSON',

    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID' => PAYPAL_API_APPLICATION_ID,

    'X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS' => '192.0.2.0', // :-? Also tried with my public IP address
    'X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS' => '<snip>', // Typed my account's e-mail
);
$payload = '{
    "sandboxEmailAddress": "Sender-emailAddress",
    "accountType": "PERSONAL",
    "name": {
        "firstName": "Lenny",
        "lastName": "Riceman"
    },
    "address": {
        "line1": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Austin",
        "state": "TX",
        "postalCode": "78759",
        "countryCode": "US"
    },
    "citizenshipCountryCode": "US",
    "contactPhoneNumber": "512-555-5555",
    "dateOfBirth": "1968-01-01Z",
    "createAccountWebOptions": {
        "returnUrl": "http://www.example.com/success.html"
    },
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "emailAddress": "lr12345@example.com",
    "preferredLanguageCode": "en_US",
    "registrationType": "Web",
    "requestEnvelope": {
        "errorLanguage": "en_US"
    }
}';
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POST => false,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

try{
    $curl = curl_init($endpoing);
    if(!$curl){
        throw new Exception('Could not initialize curl');
    }
    if(!curl_setopt_array($curl, $options)){
        throw new Exception('Curl error:' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){
        throw new Exception('Curl error:' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $result;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... but I always get this back:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/aa">
    <responseEnvelope>
        <timestamp>2013-03-20T16:33:46.309-07:00</timestamp>
        <ack>Failure</ack>
        <correlationId>7d7fa53e6a930</correlationId>
        <build>5343121</build>
    </responseEnvelope>
    <error>
        <errorId>520003</errorId>
        <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
        <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
        <severity>Error</severity>
        <category>Application</category>
        <message>Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.</message>
    </error>
</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

I've double-checked the API credentials (user, pass and signature) and they're exactly as displayed in the profile page. I'm not fully sure of `X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS` and `X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS`.

I suspect I've misread something or omitted some curl option. Can you spot what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhat unhelpfully, the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option does **not** take a hash of Header=>Value pairs, only a list of strings, each of which must be a complete HTTP header.

So instead of `$headers = array('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' => PAYPAL_API_USER, ...)` you need `$headers = array('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ' . PAYPAL_API_USER, ...)`

Comment: Yes, of course... I must be blind! And this explains why I was getting an XML error message rather than a JSON one. Thank you very much.

Comment: After fixing this I still got the same error message (except that nicely formatted in JSON). In the end, I downloaded some PHP samples from PayPal.com that happened to have a config file with API credentials from God knows who. I tried those and it all started working. So, for some reason, PayPal has assigned me an API password that is not valid. (But of course, my stupid misuse of curl was the obvious problem in my code.)

Comment: Hi all, I have the authentication failed error. I got the API from paypal site. I created the sandbox accounts in developer site. I have checked the headers too. But I could not solve this error. please suggest me.

Comment: @user2003356, ask Your own question. Álvaro, can You put there this credentials? Because I have identical problem as You :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using the wrong api credentials. You need to set up a user within your main developer account. Once that is set up, you will see on their profile that they have their own separate API credentials.

I had the same problem and took hours to solve, but all works good now.

Comment: While this doesn't answer this precise question (I was in fact misusing Curl) that was indeed the big stopper that made me waste several days. But even now I know how to do it, it normally takes several hours to set up a few test accounts for development.

Comment: +1. To set up sandbox accounts, go to developer.paypal.com, click Applications, and Sandbox Accounts is right there.

Answer (score 0):

It does say quite clearly that the APP-ID for the sandbox is always `APP-80W284485P519543T`.

When you go live you'll have your own.